# Emulate a "mouse Up" Action for a PDF

Tags: python, adobe

This is my action on Acrobat PDF.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR9uV.png)

It triggers scripts that calculate the sum and the average of the entries of a column. This works fine; the problem is that I can't fill out the PDF manually. I made it with Python and [fillpdf](https://pypi.org/project/fillpdf/).

Then new fields are written by fillpdf, the trigger "Mouse Up" doesn't happen. I can not change the PDF form structure, but I can and want to change my script to trigger the action to force my PDF Browser(Adobe Reader/Acrobat) to calculate and write the sum and average of the entries of a column.

I was thinking about an ugly workaround where I calculate on my own the sum and the average and write the results to the fields by fillpdf.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.